# How to modify height of scroll view while ReadMore option at textview in Android?

Tags: android

I'm implemented add **“...Read More”** and **"...Less"** at the end of Text View after 2 lines. When I click on read more **Scroll-View** height will be increased but when I click on less at the end of Text-View I want to less/decrease the height of scroll view. How to manage Scroll View height click on Read More options?

Here is my ExpandableTextView code.

```
public class ExpandableTextView extends TextView {
    private static final int DEFAULT_TRIM_LENGTH = 100;
    private static final String ELLIPSIS = " .....Read More";

    private CharSequence originalText;
    private CharSequence trimmedText;
    private BufferType bufferType;
    private boolean trim = true;
    private int trimLength;

    public ExpandableTextView(Context context) {
        this(context, null);
    }

    public ExpandableTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);

        TypedArray typedArray = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.ExpandableTextView);
        this.trimLength = typedArray.getInt(R.styleable.ExpandableTextView_trimLength, DEFAULT_TRIM_LENGTH);
        typedArray.recycle();

        setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                trim = !trim;
                setText();
                requestFocusFromTouch();


               // if click on read more trim is false
                if (trim == false)
                {
                    Log.e("", " trim=" + trim);
                }
                // if click on less trim is false
                else if (trim == true) {
                    Log.e("", " trim=" + trim);
                }
            }
        });
    }


    private void setText() {
        super.setText(getDisplayableText(), bufferType);

    }

    private CharSequence getDisplayableText() {

        return trim ? trimmedText : originalText;

    }

    @Override
    public void setText(CharSequence text, BufferType type)
    {

        originalText = text;
        trimmedText = getTrimmedText(text);
        Log.e(""," trimmedText ="+ trimmedText );
        bufferType = type;
        setText();
    }

    private CharSequence getTrimmedText(CharSequence text)
    {
        if (originalText != null && originalText.length() > trimLength)
        {

            return new SpannableStringBuilder(originalText, 0, trimLength + 1).append(ELLIPSIS);
        }
        else
        {

            return originalText;
        }
    }

    public CharSequence getOriginalText()
    {
        return originalText;
    }

    public void setTrimLength(int trimLength)
    {

        this.trimLength = trimLength;
        trimmedText = getTrimmedText(originalText);
        setText();
    }

    public int getTrimLength()
    {

        return trimLength;
    }
}
```

Here is my activity code.

```
 ExpandableTextView txtRemark = (ExpandableTextView)findViewById(R.id.expandable_text);
        int strRemarkLength = strRemark.length();
        if(strRemarkLength > 100)
        {
            txtRemark.setText(strRemark.concat(" ...Less"));
            Log.e("", " Lesss !!!");

            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams scrollViewParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, 350);
            scrollViewParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, txtInspectorname.getId());
            scrollViewParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, relativeLayout.getId());

            scrollView.setFillViewport(true);
            scrollView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#00000000"));
            scrollView.setScrollContainer(false);
            scrollView.setLayoutParams(scrollViewParams);

        }
        else
        {
            txtRemark.setText(strRemark);
            Log.e("", "Not Lesss !!!");

            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams scrollViewParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, 100);
            scrollViewParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, txtInspectorname.getId());
            scrollViewParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, relativeLayout.getId());

            scrollView.setFillViewport(true);
            scrollView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#00000000"));
            scrollView.setScrollContainer(false);
            scrollView.setLayoutParams(scrollViewParams);

        }
```

Comment: have look on [this](https://github.com/borjabravo10/ReadMoreTextView)

Answer (score 0):

I don't see the reason to write your own Textview in order to implement readmore future of textview while you can implement it easily by setting the maximum line of the textview programmatically. Use the android Textview and add another textview for readmore below your textview. For example, assume you have a tvReadMore textview below your txtRemark textview. First check if the text for your txtRemark textview is more enough to display the tvReadMore. if so, set the maxLine of your txtRemark to Integer.MAX_VALUE. Take a look at the following sample code

```
if(strRemark.length() > 100) { //assuming you want to show the [Read more] for more than 100 characters
   if(tvReadMore.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("Read more")) { //you should set the text of tvReadMore textview to [Read more] in the beginning
       txtRemark.setMaxLines(Integer.MAX_VALUE); //set the maximum line to Maximum integer
       tvReadMore.setText("Show Less")
   } else {
        txtRemark.setMaxLines(3); //set the maximum line to 3
        tvReadMore.setText("Read more")
   }
} else { //if there are no enough characters to show the read more text
   tvReadMore.setVisibility(View.GONE); //hide the read more textview
}
```

I have seen a lot of work arounds to implement the read more feature for textview but, in my opinion, this is the easiest and simplest way so far. The nice thing about this is, it works for both simple textview and a textview in a recyclerview.
if you want to add three dots at the end of your text, when there are more lines hidden, you can add

```
 android::ellipsize(end)
```

to your tvTitle textview.